# Powershell ftp upload error 530 not logged in

Tags: powershell, ftp

I am struggling to get a PowerShell script to work.  I am very new to PowerShell so could be missing something stupid.

```
$sourceuri = "ftp://ftp.example.com/myfolder/myfile.xml"
$username = "user"
$password = "password"

# Create a FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the ftp server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($sourceuri)

$credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
# set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = $credentials

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::UploadFile
$ftprequest.UseBinary = 1
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = 0

# read in the file to upload as a byte array
$content = gc -en byte $fileName
$ftprequest.ContentLength = $content.Length
# get the request stream, and write the bytes into it
$rs = $ftprequest.GetRequestStream()
$rs.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)
# be sure to clean up after ourselves
$rs.Close()
$rs.Dispose()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception calling "GetRequestStream" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an   error: (530) Not logged in."
At C:\temp\copyfile.ps1:63 char:35
+ $rs = $ftprequest.GetRequestStream( <<<< )
```

I can connect via IE to it easily so thought maybe something else was wrong so did this quickly in C#:

```
        string filePath = @"C:\temp\myfile.xml";
        string FTPAddress = @"ftp://ftp.example.com/myfolder";
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(FTPAddress + "/" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        string username = "user";
        string password = "password";
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        request.ContentLength = file.Length;
        int buffLength = 2048;
        byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
        int contentLen;

        FileStream fs = file.OpenRead();

        Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream();
        contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        while(contentLen !=0 )
        {
            strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
            contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        strm.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

The C# works perfectly, not sure why this isn't working and hoping someone might be able to point out my error

**EDIT**

Solved it, new it would be something stupid.  The password had a "$" sign in it, it was within double quotes but I didn't realize it would need to be escaped, just didn't think of it at all.  Ironically I had to change the password etc so that it was safe to post.

Comment: I can't see anything. The only difference is that you use `UsePassive` in you C# solution. To avoid errors you might use `Set-StrictMode -version ...` to avoid uninitialized variables (=typos), but in this case I think it won't bring anything new.

Comment: Hi Stej, thanks for the response.  I am glad its not just me, I tried to replicate the C# in PowerShell.

Comment: Many errors lead to 'problem$' with double quotes :)

Comment: Thank you for posting the edit to solved it.  This just helped me, as our password contained a $ as well.

Comment: Agreed, your edit solved it for me too! Thanks.

Comment: So. 6 years later ... 
You should answer your own question and mark it answered ... so it will get off the top of the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the reason was that the FTP server required SSL. Changing this property on the request solved my problem:

```
request.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

From the original poster [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6486/jon):

Solved it, new it would be something stupid. The password had a "$" sign in it, it was within double quotes but I didn't realize it would need to be escaped, just didn't think of it at all. Ironically I had to change the password etc so that it was safe to post.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the double quote from username or password because sometimes $ sign causes problem. Its good to use single quote every time.